# How to read SPI memory with raspberry pi? (using wiringpi)

Tags: gpio, spi, wiringpi

This is the pinout I have for the flash memory W25Q128FV which I'm trying to interact with

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to control it with a raspberry pi 3 B+.

Here's how I wired everything:

```
CS - GND
D0 - SPIMISO
WP - GND
GND - GND
VCC - 3.3v
HOLD - 3.3v
CLK - SPISCLK
DI - SPIMOSI
```

**CS is in GND because datasheet says that in LOW, we can write/read from the chip,** but I think this is wrong. I need to connect this to some raspberry pi pin that maybe is controlled by wiring pi.

I also enabled spi on raspberry and I'm using the library **wiringPi** with channel 0.

I'm writing like this (Rust code linked against -lwiringPi):

```
pub fn read_status_register_3(&self) -> [u8;2]{
    let mut slice :[u8;2] = [0;2];
    let mut data: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 2] = [0;2];
    data[0] = 0x11;
    let mut _r: i32 = 0;
    _r = unsafe{wiringPiSPIDataRW (self.spi_channel,data.as_mut_ptr(), data.len() as i32)};
    slice.clone_from_slice(&data);
    slice
}
```

but I get `data` to be all `0`. I suspect something is wrong but I don't know if it's on the chip, on the wiring or on the software. This is a brand new chip by the way.

datasheet link: http://www.xmcwh.com/Uploads/2020-09-03/5f50d26953af2.pdf

Here's my Rust code with everything ready to test and dockerized, just `./run.sh`, compile the Wiringpi/wiringpi with `./build` and `cargo run` in `w25qxx_spi`: https://github.com/lucaszanella/w25qxx_spi/blob/b652db39d83521d7f018bd254c1b3dca03549f00/w25qxx_spi/src/w25q.rs

Comment: You're probably aware that `wiringPi` has been [deprecated](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/). It still works - at least I still use it occasionally, but if you've not used it much, you should be aaware that is uses a unique numbering scheme for GPIO pins. You can print those from wiringPi, or use [this tool](https://pinout.xyz/#), and hover over the pin to see the "tool tip".

Comment: I suggest you get it working using a more supported environment such as C or Python.  When that is working port the code to Rust.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Have to connecto CS to SPICS0 which is a pin on the rpi

Comment: Congratulations! Please "accept" your answer as the correct one when you are able. his will prevent the question from becoming a *zombie*  :)